# J2ME: block incoming call

Tags: java, java-me

I am working in J2ME, want to make an application to block incoming calls from some certain numbers. Is this possible to block some numbers using programming in J2ME?

Comment: Already tried to [googling](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?101562-API-for-call-blocking)?

Comment: Yes @Crazenezz I have googled it. and visited link sent by you. According to that post we can not block a number using J2ME, but as you can see that post is 5 year back, So i thing someone has resolved this issue. Thats why I posted my question here...

Comment: I got [this](http://weblog.cenriqueortiz.com/javame,j2me/2005/11/29/mobile-telephony-api-mta-for-java-me/). Hope will useful to you...

Answer (score 4):

No, there is absolutely no way to do this in J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your platform. Some manufacturers delivers ME with proprietary classes for AT command interface.

With AT command interface you can use [CLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID) feature. 
When someone is calling, software can check phonenumber from the `+CLIP` URC. And dedicate to answer or hang-up the incoming call.

That of cource does not prevent the calling, but it prevent answering.

Comment: Do they really?  Can you give examples of platforms that offer such APIs?

Comment: @funkybro : Siemens TC45 and Cinterion Tc65i. Both have com.siemens.icm.io package for that purpose.